# Unit tests for an argument-checking class

Tags: java, unit-testing

I am wondering if my current unit tests could be written better, I am most interested in whether it is possible to make the code look more concise, as currently it a *boiler-plated mess*.
I have full access to Java 8, if that would help by making it more concise.

The `Arguments` class itself:

```
public final class Arguments {
    private Arguments() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    public static int requirePositive(final int value) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        return requirePositive(value, "value");
    }

    public static int requirePositive(final int value, final String name) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        Objects.requireNonNull(name);
        if (value <= 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("the " + name + " must be positive: " + value);
        }
        return value;
    }

    public static int requireNegative(final int value) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        return requireNegative(value, "value");
    }

    public static int requireNegative(final int value, final String name) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        Objects.requireNonNull(name);
        if (value >= 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("the " + name + " must be negative: " + value);
        }
        return value;
    }

    public static int requirePositiveOrZero(final int value) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        return requirePositiveOrZero(value, "value");
    }

    public static int requirePositiveOrZero(final int value, final String name) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        Objects.requireNonNull(name);
        if (value < 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("the " + name + " must be positive or zero: " + value);
        }
        return value;
    }

    public static int requireNegativeOrZero(final int value) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        return requireNegativeOrZero(value, "value");
    }

    public static int requireNegativeOrZero(final int value, final String name) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        Objects.requireNonNull(name);
        if (value > 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("the " + name + " must be negative or zero: " + value);
        }
        return value;
    }

    public static int requireInRange(final int value, final int lowInclusive, final int highExclusive) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        return requireInRange(value, lowInclusive, highExclusive, "value");
    }

    public static int requireInRange(final int value, final int lowInclusive, final int highExclusive, final String name) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        Objects.requireNonNull(name);
        if (lowInclusive >= highExclusive) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("the lower inclusive bound is greater or equal to the higher exclusive bound: " + lowInclusive + " >= " + highExclusive);
        }
        if (value < lowInclusive || value >= highExclusive) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("the " + name + " was not in range: " + value + ", expected: [" + lowInclusive + ", " + highExclusive + ")");
        }
        return value;
    }

    public static int requireInRangeClosed(final int value, final int lowInclusive, final int highInclusive) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        return requireInRangeClosed(value, lowInclusive, highInclusive, "value");
    }

    public static int requireInRangeClosed(final int value, final int lowInclusive, final int highInclusive, final String name) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        Objects.requireNonNull(name);
        if (lowInclusive > highInclusive) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("the lower inclusive bound is greater or equal to the higher inclusive bound: " + lowInclusive + " >= " + highInclusive);
        }
        if (value < lowInclusive || value > highInclusive) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("the " + name + " was not in range: " + value + ", expected: [" + lowInclusive + ", " + highInclusive + ")]");
        }
        return value;
    }

    public static int requireIndexInRange(final int index, final int lowInclusive, final int highExclusive) throws IndexOutOfBoundsException {
        if (lowInclusive >= highExclusive) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("the lower inclusive bound is greater or equal to the higher exclusive bound: " + lowInclusive + " >= " + highExclusive);
        }
        if (index < lowInclusive || index >= highExclusive) {
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("the index was not in range: " + index + ", expected: [" + lowInclusive + ", " + highExclusive + ")");
        }
        return index;
    }

    public static int requireIndexInRangeClosed(final int index, final int lowInclusive, final int highInclusive) throws IndexOutOfBoundsException {
        if (lowInclusive > highInclusive) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("the lower inclusive bound is greater or equal to the higher inclusive bound: " + lowInclusive + " >= " + highInclusive);
        }
        if (index < lowInclusive || index > highInclusive) {
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("the index was not in range: " + index + ", expected: [" + lowInclusive + ", " + highInclusive + "]");
        }
        return index;
    }
}
```

The `ArgumentsTest` test class:

```
public class ArgumentsTest {
    static {
        assertTrue(true);
    }

    /** Arguments.requirePositive **/

    @Test
    public void testRequirePositive_int() {
        int result = Arguments.requirePositive(1);
        assertEquals(1, result);
    }

    @Test(expected = IllegalArgumentException.class)
    public void testRequirePositive_intIAE1() {
        Arguments.requirePositive(0);
    }

    @Test(expected = IllegalArgumentException.class)
    public void testRequirePositive_intIAE2() {
        Arguments.requirePositive(-1);
    }

    @Test
    public void testRequirePositive_int_String() {
        int result = Arguments.requirePositive(1, "test");
        assertEquals(1, result);
    }

    @Test(expected = IllegalArgumentException.class)
    public void testRequirePositive_int_StringIAE1() {
        Arguments.requirePositive(0, "test");
    }

    @Test(expected = IllegalArgumentException.class)
    public void testRequirePositive_int_StringIAE2() {
        Arguments.requirePositive(-1, "test");
    }

    @Test(expected = NullPointerException.class)
    public void testRequirePositive_int_StringNPE() {
        Arguments.requirePositive(1, null);
    }

    /** Arguments.requireNegative **/

    @Test
    public void testRequireNegative_int() {
        int result = Arguments.requireNegative(-1);
        assertEquals(-1, result);
    }

    @Test(expected = IllegalArgumentException.class)
    public void testRequireNegative_intIAE1() {
        Arguments.requireNegative(0);
    }

    @Test(expected = IllegalArgumentException.class)
    public void testRequireNegative_intIAE2() {
        Arguments.requireNegative(1);
    }

    @Test
    public void testRequireNegative_int_String() {
        int result = Arguments.requireNegative(-1, "test");
        assertEquals(-1, result);
    }

    @Test(expected = IllegalArgumentException.class)
    public void testRequireNegative_int_StringIAE1() {
        Arguments.requireNegative(0, "test");
    }

    @Test(expected = IllegalArgumentException.class)
    public void testRequireNegative_int_StringIAE2() {
        Arguments.requireNegative(1, "test");
    }

    @Test(expected = NullPointerException.class)
    public void testRequireNegative_int_StringNPE() {
        Arguments.requireNegative(-1, null);
    }

    /** Arguments.requirePositiveOrZero **/

    @Test
    public void testRequirePositiveOrZero_int1() {
        int result = Arguments.requirePositiveOrZero(0);
        assertEquals(0, result);
    }

    @Test
    public void testRequirePositiveOrZero_int2() {
        int result = Arguments.requirePositiveOrZero(1);
        assertEquals(1, result);
    }

    @Test(expected = IllegalArgumentException.class)
    public void testRequirePositiveOrZero_intIAE() {
        Arguments.requirePositiveOrZero(-1);
    }

    @Test
    public void testRequirePositiveOrZero_int_String1() {
        int result = Arguments.requirePositiveOrZero(0, "test");
        assertEquals(0, result);
    }

    @Test
    public void testRequirePositiveOrZero_int_String2() {
        int result = Arguments.requirePositiveOrZero(1, "test");
        assertEquals(1, result);
    }

    @Test(expected = IllegalArgumentException.class)
    public void testRequirePositiveOrZero_int_StringIAE() {
        Arguments.requirePositiveOrZero(-1, "test");
    }

    @Test(expected = NullPointerException.class)
    public void testRequirePositiveOrZero_int_StringNPE() {
        Arguments.requirePositiveOrZero(0, null);
    }

    /** Arguments.requireNegativeOrZero **/

    @Test
    public void testRequireNegativeOrZero_int1() {
        int result = Arguments.requireNegativeOrZero(0);
        assertEquals(0, result);
    }

    @Test
    public void testRequireNegativeOrZero_int2() {
        int result = Arguments.requireNegativeOrZero(-1);
        assertEquals(-1, result);
    }

    @Test(expected = IllegalArgumentException.class)
    public void testRequireNegativeOrZero_intIAE() {
        Arguments.requireNegativeOrZero(1);
    }

    @Test
    public void testRequireNegativeOrZero_int_String1() {
        int result = Arguments.requireNegativeOrZero(0, "test");
        assertEquals(0, result);
    }

    @Test
    public void testRequireNegativeOrZero_int_String2() {
        int result = Arguments.requireNegativeOrZero(-1, "test");
        assertEquals(-1, result);
    }

    @Test(expected = IllegalArgumentException.class)
    public void testRequireNegativeOrZero_int_StringIAE() {
        Arguments.requireNegativeOrZero(1, "test");
    }

    @Test(expected = NullPointerException.class)
    public void testRequireNegativeOrZero_int_StringNPE() {
        Arguments.requireNegativeOrZero(0, null);
    }

    /** Arguments.requireInRange **/

    @Test
    public void testRequireInRange_3args() {
        int result = Arguments.requireInRange(1, 1, 2);
        assertEquals(1, result);
        int result2 = Arguments.requireInRange(1, 0, 3);
        assertEquals(1, result2);
    }

    @Test(expected = IllegalArgumentException.class)
    public void testRequireInRange_3argsIAE1() {
        Arguments.requireInRange(1, 5, 5);
    }

    @Test(expected = IllegalArgumentException.class)
    public void testRequireInRange_3argsIAE2() {
        Arguments.requireInRange(1, 6, 5);
    }

    @Test(expected = IllegalArgumentException.class)
    public void testRequireInRange_3argsIAE3() {
        Arguments.requireInRange(1, 0, 1);
    }

    @Test(expected = IllegalArgumentException.class)
    public void testRequireInRange_3argsIAE4() {
        Arguments.requireInRange(1, 2, 5);
    }

    @Test(expected = IllegalArgumentException.class)
    public void testRequireInRange_3argsIAE5() {
        Arguments.requireInRange(1, 10, 20);
    }

    @Test
    public void testRequireInRange_4args() {
        int result = Arguments.requireInRange(1, 1, 2, "test");
        assertEquals(1, result);
        int result2 = Arguments.requireInRange(1, 0, 3, "test");
        assertEquals(1, result2);
    }

    @Test(expected = IllegalArgumentException.class)
    public void testRequireInRange_4argsIAE1() {
        Arguments.requireInRange(1, 5, 5, "test");
    }

    @Test(expected = IllegalArgumentException.class)
    public void testRequireInRange_4argsIAE2() {
        Arguments.requireInRange(1, 6, 5, "test");
    }

    @Test(expected = IllegalArgumentException.class)
    public void testRequireInRange_4argsIAE3() {
        Arguments.requireInRange(1, 0, 1, "test");
    }

    @Test(expected = IllegalArgumentException.class)
    public void testRequireInRange_4argsIAE4() {
        Arguments.requireInRange(1, 2, 5, "test");
    }

    @Test(expected = IllegalArgumentException.class)
    public void testRequireInRange_4argsIAE5() {
        Arguments.requireInRange(1, 10, 20, "test");
    }

    @Test(expected = NullPointerException.class)
    public void testRequireInRange_4argsNPE() {
        Arguments.requireInRange(1, 0, 2, null);
    }

    /** Arguments.requireInRangeClosed **/

    @Test
    public void testRequireInRangeClosed_3args() {
        int result = Arguments.requireInRangeClosed(1, 1, 2);
        assertEquals(1, result);
        int result2 = Arguments.requireInRangeClosed(1, 0, 1);
        assertEquals(1, result2);
        int result3 = Arguments.requireInRangeClosed(1, 1, 1);
        assertEquals(1, result3);
    }

    @Test(expected = IllegalArgumentException.class)
    public void testRequireInRangeClosed_3argsIAE1() {
        Arguments.requireInRangeClosed(1, 6, 5);
    }

    @Test(expected = IllegalArgumentException.class)
    public void testRequireInRangeClosed_3argsIAE2() {
        Arguments.requireInRangeClosed(1, -4, 0);
    }

    @Test(expected = IllegalArgumentException.class)
    public void testRequireInRangeClosed_3argsIAE3() {
        Arguments.requireInRangeClosed(1, 2, 5);
    }

    @Test(expected = IllegalArgumentException.class)
    public void testRequireInRangeClosed_3argsIAE4() {
        Arguments.requireInRangeClosed(1, 20, 40);
    }

    @Test
    public void testRequireInRangeClosed_4args() {
        int result = Arguments.requireInRangeClosed(1, 1, 2, "test");
        assertEquals(1, result);
        int result2 = Arguments.requireInRangeClosed(1, 0, 1, "test");
        assertEquals(1, result2);
        int result3 = Arguments.requireInRangeClosed(1, 1, 1, "test");
        assertEquals(1, result3);
    }

    @Test(expected = IllegalArgumentException.class)
    public void testRequireInRangeClosed_4argsIAE1() {
        Arguments.requireInRangeClosed(1, 6, 5, "test");
    }

    @Test(expected = IllegalArgumentException.class)
    public void testRequireInRangeClosed_4argsIAE2() {
        Arguments.requireInRangeClosed(1, -4, 0, "test");
    }

    @Test(expected = IllegalArgumentException.class)
    public void testRequireInRangeClosed_4argsIAE3() {
        Arguments.requireInRangeClosed(1, 2, 5, "test");
    }

    @Test(expected = IllegalArgumentException.class)
    public void testRequireInRangeClosed_4argsIAE4() {
        Arguments.requireInRangeClosed(1, 20, 40, "test");
    }

    @Test(expected = NullPointerException.class)
    public void testRequireInRangeClosed_4argsNPE() {
        Arguments.requireInRangeClosed(5, 2, 20, null);
    }

    /** Arguments.requireIndexInRange **/

    @Test
    public void testRequireIndexInRange() {
        int result = Arguments.requireIndexInRange(1, 1, 2);
        assertEquals(1, result);
        int result2 = Arguments.requireIndexInRange(1, 0, 3);
        assertEquals(1, result2);
    }

    @Test(expected = IllegalArgumentException.class)
    public void testRequireIndexInRangeIAE1() {
        Arguments.requireIndexInRange(1, 5, 5);
    }

    @Test(expected = IllegalArgumentException.class)
    public void testRequireIndexInRangeIAE2() {
        Arguments.requireIndexInRange(1, 6, 5);
    }

    @Test(expected = IndexOutOfBoundsException.class)
    public void testRequireIndexInRangeIAE3() {
        Arguments.requireIndexInRange(1, 0, 1);
    }

    @Test(expected = IndexOutOfBoundsException.class)
    public void testRequireIndexInRangeIAE4() {
        Arguments.requireIndexInRange(1, 2, 5);
    }

    @Test(expected = IndexOutOfBoundsException.class)
    public void testRequireIndexInRangeIAE5() {
        Arguments.requireIndexInRange(1, 10, 20);
    }

    /** Arguments.requireIndexInRangeClosed **/

    @Test
    public void testRequireIndexInRangeClosed() {
        int result = Arguments.requireIndexInRangeClosed(1, 1, 2);
        assertEquals(1, result);
        int result2 = Arguments.requireIndexInRangeClosed(1, 0, 1);
        assertEquals(1, result2);
        int result3 = Arguments.requireIndexInRangeClosed(1, 1, 1);
        assertEquals(1, result3);
    }

    @Test(expected = IllegalArgumentException.class)
    public void testRequireIndexInRangeClosedIAE1() {
        Arguments.requireIndexInRangeClosed(1, 6, 5);
    }

    @Test(expected = IndexOutOfBoundsException.class)
    public void testRequireIndexInRangeClosedIAE2() {
        Arguments.requireIndexInRangeClosed(1, -4, 0);
    }

    @Test(expected = IndexOutOfBoundsException.class)
    public void testRequireIndexInRangeClosedIAE3() {
        Arguments.requireIndexInRangeClosed(1, 2, 5);
    }

    @Test(expected = IndexOutOfBoundsException.class)
    public void testRequireIndexInRangeClosedIAE4() {
        Arguments.requireIndexInRangeClosed(1, 20, 40);
    }
}
```

Some extra notes:

- Using JUnit 4.x
- The `static { assertTrue(true); }` is there to prevent Netbeans from removing the import if it would be unused in some test class.
- All the non-named variants of my argument methods refer to the named-variant, but this is an **implementation detail**, and unit tests are not allowed to know about the implementation.
- All code in question may of course be reviewed and I would appreciate *all* comments, even though the question is mainly about the unit tests.
- Did I mention already that the test class feels way too bulky for what it is actually doing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Test Names**

`testRequirePositive_intIAE1()` doesn't tell me anything besides what function is being tested. It is helpful to give some context as to why you think it should throw an exception. What makes `testRequirePositive_intIAE1()` different from `testRequirePositive_intIAE2()`? You have to go look at the test to know what is actually being tested. In this case, it is easy to deduce why the argument is invalid, but this will not be the case for more complicated methods.

---

**Repetitiveness**

As you pointed out, the test code is bulky and some times hard to follow. When you look at the code, there are lots of cases where each tests is doing the exact same thing, but with different inputs.

This is a perfect case for [parameterized tests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10143872/210526). You provide the data with a static method and your test class is instantiated once for each data set.

Touching on the previous point: Parameterized tests mean your actual test method can't describe why the data is intended to cause an error. So it is a good idea to include an additional `String` argument to provide that context.

---

**Multiple Asserts**

`testRequireIndexInRangeClosed()`<sup>1</sup> has three different assertions that are unrelated. These should be different tests (probably different data inputs for a parameterized test). This issue with this is that if the first assertion fails, the following assertions are not checked. This can hide information about what is wrong with the system.

<sup>1</sup> This is not the only instance of this in the test code.

---

**Long Class**

Just because all of the tested methods are in the same class doesn't mean all of the tests have to be in the same class too. Organize your tests just as you would with your actual code. If a class or method is too long, it likely means you should break it into smaller pieces.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what [@unholysampler](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/15893/unholysampler) already said, I would offer some practical but **very opinionated** tips to writing unit tests.

I don't really understand why you require the `name` parameters to be non-null. Your implementation doesn't need them to be. I think these checks violate the [YAGNI doctrine](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?YouArentGonnaNeedIt).

In addition, I think it's redundant to write separate unit tests for the two variants of each method, one with a `String name` parameter and one without. If you write tests for just the methods without `name`, you will already cover all execution paths, so why bother? (Of course, assuming you can don't mind getting rid of the `name != null` requirement.)

---

Instead of this:

> ```
> int result = Arguments.requireInRange(1, 1, 2);
> assertEquals(1, result);
> int result2 = Arguments.requireInRange(1, 0, 3);
> assertEquals(1, result2);
> ```

why not simply:

```
assertEquals(1, Arguments.requireInRange(1, 1, 2));
assertEquals(1, Arguments.requireInRange(1, 0, 3));
```

It's NOT less readable (might be actually more readable), and it saves you the pain of the throw-away local variables.

Actually I would write it more like this:

```
int min = 10;
int max = 20;
assertEquals(min, Arguments.requireInRange(min + 1, min, max));
assertEquals(min, Arguments.requireInRange(min, min, max));
assertEquals(max - 1, Arguments.requireInRange(max - 1, min, max));
```

This way I find it easier to understand how the arguments of `requireInRange` were chosen and the purpose of those assertions.